# Hypothetically speaking, how could adding a protected variable in a superclass create an error in Java?

Tags: java

Just for fun, I'm trying to think of a scenario in which a protected variable can cause a compilation error. Lets say you had a class Fruit and a class Apple which inherits from Fruit.

And then you go ahead and add a protected variable x in Fruit, causing the program to no longer compile. Could this happen if so how, what would be causing the error?

Comment: I don't believe that can happen. They deliberately implemented [field hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) so that couldn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

`x` will be inherited by `Apple` without problems. You will be able to use it inside either `Fruit` or `Apple`. You might decide to override it and/or implement setter and/or getter.